# Angular : Import JSON File From Server, external to the project, without using Get Method

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, production-environment

I wish to **import a Json file**, **external to the Angular application**, **in production.**
This file would be located in the same folder as index.html and the build files by angular. (See image below).

The goal is to be able to edit this file freely without having to rebuild the application.

But three problems arise for me:

- I can't use the Http.Get() because of constraints on the server side.
- I can't import a JSON file with a relative URL. I also, tried to use asset as starting point but it did'nt work.
- I can not store the JSON in environment.prod.ts, since i need to be able to modify it without rebuilding the application.

So I don't know how to access this json file, or even if it is possible with the constraints mentioned above.

I use IIS to create the server locally, in case this information has any importance.

[image: Production Folder Exemple]

Comment: Hmm.. why can’t you use a GET..?

Comment: @MikeOne Serveur Constraint. I need to read the file before authentification. However, the server gonna block the access if i'm not authentified

Comment: you can import a json file as mentioned [here](https://www.techiediaries.com/import-local-json-files-in-typescript/)

Comment: also if you could provide more context related to what you are intending to do with the output json, it might help